# how can I format DateTime using Anorm?

Tags: scala, datetime, anorm

I get the "time" from mysql and need to render it to fe, but I get the "time" in the form of timestamp and I want it displayed as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, how can I do it in the server code as follows?

```
object JDItem {

  val jditem = {
    get[Long]("id") ~
    get[String]("name") ~
    get[String]("url") ~
    get[Double]("price") ~
    get[Int]("commentnum") ~
    get[Int]("likerate") ~
    get[DateTime]("time") ~
    get[String]("category") map {
      case id ~ name ~ url ~price~
        commentnum~likerate~time~category => JDItem(id,name,url,price,
        commentnum,likerate,time,category)
    }
  }

  implicit val JDItemWrites: Writes[JDItem] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
      (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "url").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "price").write[Double] and
      (JsPath \ "commentnum").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "likerate").write[Int] and
      (JsPath \ "time").write[DateTime] and
      (JsPath \ "category").write[String]
    )(unlift(JDItem.unapply))

  def getJson(category:String,sort:String,DescOrAsc:String):JsObject = DB.withConnection{ implicit c =>
    val list = SQL("select id,name,url,price,commentnum,likerate,time,category from "+category+" order by "+sort+" "+DescOrAsc+" limit 100").as(jditem *)
    val json:JsValue = Json.toJson(list)
    val jsobject = Json.obj("total"-> list.length,"rows"-> json)
    jsobject
  }
```

}

Comment: More of a side note, but that code looks vulnerable to sql injection if the category can be specific by an external caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 2.3.8 of Anorm, Joda & Java8 temporal types are supported in result parser; see [Anorm column](https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/docs/manual/working/scalaGuide/main/sql/ScalaAnorm.md#column-parsers): `get[DateTime]`.

Comment: Nothing prevent you from formatting the `DateTime` in the `.map` of the parser.